# use file or filename in XML

Tags: joomla-4.x, xml

What tags do I correctly use in the XML file to install an extension to add a file?
`filename` or `file`?

In example code (https://codeberg.org/astrid/j4examplecode/src/branch/tutorial/src/plugins/content/indieweb/indieweb.xml) I found

```
<file>indieweb.xml</file>
```

That works. But:

Now I found in Joomla Core (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/75d6c4970d2940ae8fdebe52335ab5411b52f4ea/plugins/content/contact/contact.xml#LL13C3-L13C52)

```
<filename plugin="contact">contact.php</filename>
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each file to copy must be represented by a `<filename>` element. If you want to copy an entire folder at once, you can define it as a `<folder>`.

Useful resource to consult: https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files